# EventBrite OAuth2.0 redirect url not working

Tags: wordpress, redirect, oauth, oauth-2.0, eventbrite

We are building a wordpress site integrated with the EventBrite API, 
and since last week we've been getting an error everytime the user is being redirected back to our site.

For example when i set `www.google.com` as my redirect URL, I would be redirected to `www.google.com/www.google.com`, and as a result the webserver would return an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you double-checked [your API Key](http://eventbrite.com/api/key/)'s [redirect_uri  settings](http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/authentication/oauth2/)?

Feel free to contact the [Eventbrite API team](http://developer.eventbrite.com/contact-us/) for help with these kinds of questions.